# Groovy oneliner not able to print environment variable

Tags: groovy

I am trying this groovy one-line its not working. Any idea how to make this work?

```
groovy -e 'def env=System.getenv();println( env['HOME'])'

Caught: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: HOME for class: script_from_command_line
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: HOME for class: script_from_command_line
        at script_from_command_line.run(script_from_command_line:1)
```

Thanks
SR

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
groovy -e "def env=System.getenv();println( env['HOME'])"
```

just use different quotes for string and for whole command

other ways

```
groovy -e "def env=System.getenv();println( env.HOME )"
groovy -e "println System.getenv().HOME"
groovy -e "println(System.env.HOME)"
```